# Need to Give User Group Ability to Edit Documents but not Download or Sync Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups, sharepoint-permissions

Have a Requirement to have a User Group be able to Edit Documents, but not be able to download them or sync the library in a O365 Online Sharepoint Site.

But I need other users to be able to still sync the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SPO, if the user has the edit permission, it does not support the prohibition of downloading documents.

If you want to disable synchronization, you could refer to:
[How to disable sync in SharePoint and OneDrive](http://How%20to%20disable%20sync%20in%20SharePoint%20and%20OneDrive)

Comment: Thanks this is what all my investigation so far had pointed to but I am no Sharepoint expert.